# d3 Pack layout - Bubbles are overlapping if the data have '0' values

Tags: d3.js

I have created a packed bubble chart using d3.layout.pack() for the following json which contains '0' values.

```
{ "children": [{ "className": "a", "value": 0},
{ "className": "b", "value": 1},
{ "className": "c", "value": 0},
{ "className": "d", "value": 0},
{ "className": "f", "value": 0},
{ "className": "g", "value": 8},
{ "className": "h", "value": 2},
{ "className": "i", "value": 6},
{ "className": "j", "value": 8},
{ "className": "k", "value": 4},
{ "className": "l", "value": 3}] };
```

While creating this chart, some bubble are overlapping.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/remila_antony/chrrp3ww/

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/1761). According to Mike Bostock:

> Probably [you] should just filter out zero values (even very small values) when computing the pack layout. The problem is the pack intersection test fails when the two values being compared are very different (one is very small, say near zero, and the other very large).

Thus, the solution is filtering out the zeros:

```
flat.children = flat.children.filter(d=>d.value>0);
```

Here is your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2umsqjt1/

Comment: I can filter the zero values. But how can I find the small values with great difference in my data? Is there any way? @Gerardo Furtado

Comment: Write a function to filter them out depending on the threshold you want.

Comment: I could not have static threshold as my data varies. So, if any Math function is available to find the threshold, it would be helpful.

Comment: As this is another problem, please post another question with all the specifications.